# How to write fast acceptance tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, acceptance-testing

I'm was writing in Java for some time and now I'm working with Rails for about one year. I was immediately put into a big project with a lot of specs (which was really new to me, I haven't used much of TDD/BDD technique earlier).

Ok, I learned the process and everything works fine, but now I would like to know how to make another step and make my specs a lot faster. In our project we have a lot of acceptance tests, where whe test a end-to-end functionality. For example user signs in, he click some button, the javascript popup appears and he submits the form. Easy functionality, but the problem is that these tests are really slow. We are using Rspec with Capybara and Selenium, so our tests has to open the browser, imitiate the user actions, wait for javascripts etc.

My question is: How to do this in a better, faster way? We have a lot of acceptance tests, and after running all specs in our project we have to wait about 30 minutes to finish.

Answer (score 1):

Use `capybara-webkit`, it's faster as it doesn't actually open the site, it just imitates the flow internally and checks if everything is fine, faster compared to Selenium, [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit) should help you get started

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it. But I wondered if there is a better way to test my applications. Maybe even don't write so many acceptance tests and use some javascript testing framework with more tests around controller/services?

Comment: Well trust me I myself hate testing, but its gotta be done, unit testing is important but in the end if scripts on the front end is not working then user experience would be effected and end to end tests is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer of @Babar are fine: using capybara-webkit; but you can evaluate PhantomJS+poltergeist too. I'm using phantomJS+poltergeist and all test are improving time of execution and plus now I can detect JS error.